# Persistence of memory allocation in Galaxybase graph database startup

Tags: graph-databases

During the startup configuration of Galaxybase, I set three different memory components. I would like to know whether these memory allocations are persistent, meaning once allocated, are they constantly occupied?I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find clear information about the persistence of memory allocation in Galaxybase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocation is a persistent occupation where the allocated space is immediately occupied. Both graph data caching and external unique identifier caching occupy memory based on their respective sizes.

Answer (score 1):

There are three memory settings in Galaxybase, among which the external unique identifier cache is not persistent, while the graph data cache and computational memory are persistent.